# Purpose of multidimensional arrays and when to use them?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have started learning about coding in C++ and I'm just starting on arrays, but I just don't understand the concept of multidimensional arrays, does it save memory and make the program faster or something else? And also under what circumstance should I use them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer not specifically C or C++.

Imagine a chess board, it has some squares. Each square can have a playing piece on it. You could store the state of each square in an array.

If you number the squares 0, 1, 2, 3 … 63 then you can put them in a one dimensional array. To go left add 1, to go right subtract 1, to go down add width (8), to go up subtract width (8) (With some bounds checking).

Alternatively you can use a 2 dimensional array 0…7, 0…7 now you do not add 8 you just add one to y dimension. Note the computer converts it all to one dimensional in the end, but C and C++ arrays have no bounds checking, and you have to keep telling it the width. There are some good classes in the library to make things easier.

Also you can have 3, 4, 5 or any other number of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

you'll get it just in practice! there are lot's of situationts where you use bidimensional arrays, just because it'll be not enough to use a simple array, for example simple backtracking problems such as labyrinths, sudoku, the lee's algorithm. Or another example: you have a table of data of students from your class, the columns is data of every student, but the raws can be: the first raw the average grade, the second raw his height, the third raw his number, and so on

Comment: generally the struct is bidimensional array

Answer (score -3):

In practice, don't use multidimensional arrays in C or C++. Just use a single dimension array, perhaps by making a `class` containing it with some getter and setter methods.

However, there are many occasions where you would use a container of containers, e.g. types like `std::set<std::vector<long>>` or occasionally `std::vector<std::array<double,3>>` etc...

The *practical* exception for using *raw* 2D arrays might be for matrixes whose dimensions are a compile-time constant. So a 3D linear transform (from *R<sup>3</sup>* to itself) might be represented by a `double m[3][3];` ; then a good [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) might even be able to [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization) the code.

But for a matrix whose both dimensions are only known at runtime, making it a bidimensional array is generally a mistake or an overkill (and this is why the STL does not provide you with a `std::matrix` template). You could use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` but that requires allocating each row of your matrix.

Of course, you'll find a lot of *existing* linear algebra libraries like [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms), etc... Use them for 2D or 3D computations. Some of them might even use hardware acceleration (e.g. using [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) to run on a GPGPU).

More generally, very often you should use and combine existing C++ [standard containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) (or even define your own templates providing your containers, perhaps by combining existing ones).

Comment: While this is a good attempt, don't try to answer that kind of unclear questions please. Didn't downvote BTW.

Comment: Best answer for a bad question. Didn't deserve the torpedo bombing.